# C: Return value via stack/register question

Tags: c, function, return-value, calling-convention

I am new to C, and there is one thing I can not understand.
When function returns something that is not bigger than register -- my compiler puts it in EAX.
When I return big structure (not pointer but structure itself) -- it is returned via stack.

My question is: how compiler knows how to call function exported by another object?
There is a calling conventions (like stdcall) but it is about passing the arguments, not reading the returned value, right?

There should be some rule like "If return value declared to be larger than EAX, than take it from [bp-...]".

And one more: would it be right to say that objects I want to return, larger than register should be stored in heap and returned by pointer to prevent all than stack manipulations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

The way that the return value is passed to the caller is part of the function calling conventions as well. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

For example, regarding `cdecl`:

> The `cdecl` calling convention is used
>   by many C systems for the x86
>   architecture. In `cdecl`, function
>   parameters are pushed on the stack in
>   a right-to-left order. Function return
>   values are returned in the EAX
>   register (except for floating point
>   values, which are returned in the x87
>   register ST0).

```
[...]
```

> There are some variations in the
>   interpretation of `cdecl`, particularly
>   in how to return values. As a result,
>   x86 programs compiled for different
>   operating system platforms and/or by
>   different compilers can be
>   incompatible, even if they both use
>   the `cdecl` convention and do not call
>   out to the underlying environment.
>   Some compilers return simple data
>   structures with the length of 2
>   registers or less in EAX:EDX, and
>   larger structures and class objects
>   requiring special treatment by the
>   exception handler (e.g., a defined
>   constructor, destructor, or
>   assignment) are returned in memory. To
>   pass "in memory", the caller allocates
>   memory and passes a pointer to it as a
>   hidden first parameter; the callee
>   populates the memory and returns the
>   pointer, popping the hidden pointer
>   when returning.

The stack manipulations are going to be much much faster than the heap manipulations necessary if you allocate memory on the heap, so stack is always faster. The only reason (in C) you might want to return a pointer to something on the heap is because it won't fit on the stack.

**Clarification:**

In the last sentence above, "the only reason you might want..." should not be interpreted as "there is normally no reason to return a pointer". Rather, I mean "*if you can do what you need without returning a pointer*, the only reason to decide to use a pointer anyway is...".

Of course there are many valid reasons to return pointers from functions as Chris states in his own answer, but I 'm only talking about the cases where you don't *need* to do so.

In other words, **return by value when you can; use pointers when you must**.

Comment: "The only reason (in C) you might want to return a pointer to something on the heap is because it won't fit on the stack." Not really true, but I've given you a +1 anyway.

Comment: @Chris: I think I miscommunicated my intent there. But +1 back for the thoughtful answer and the comments which led me to improve mine.

Comment: I didn't think you meant that sentence quite the way it sounded. I just wanted to bring it to your attention.

Comment: "stack manipulations are going to be much much faster than the heap manipulations" - why is that?

Comment: @flow2k very roughly: the stack is organized such that it can be manipulated very quickly; you pay for this by accepting restrictions on the relative lifetimes of memory allocated on it. The heap does not present any such restrictions, but you pay for this by accepting the cost of more bookkeeping.

Answer (score 4):

> And one more: would it be right to say that objects I want to return, larger than register should be stored in heap and returned by pointer to prevent all than stack manipulations?

Well, maybe. Honestly, the choice of "return by pointer" or "return by value" is one you should probably have better reasons to make than "I want the return to be faster." For example, it would be faster to return via pointer than via stack for large objects, but this isn't taking into account the greater amount of time it takes to allocate an object on the heap compared to the stack.

More importantly, return-by-pointer allows you to have opaque pointers, variably-sized objects and certain degrees of polymorphic behavior that are impossible in stack objects. If you want or need these kinds of behaviors, you should be using return-by-pointer anyway. If you don't, you can use return-by-value, or you can pass a pointer to an object allocated by the user (however they like) as a parameter and modify that parameter in your function (this is sometimes called an "out parameter" or something similar).

Choose the return method based on what you need and what your code does, not which you think is faster. If you find that you absolutely need the speed (after profiling and finding that the return is a bottleneck), *then* worry about this kind of micro-optimization.