# How do C++ functions return a big object or a structure?

Tags: c++, c, assembly

I read in [Computer Systems a programmer perspective](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/) that when one is programming in assembly code, the convention regarding the caller-callee protocol states that the returned value of a function should be stored in the `eax` (or the analogue `rax`, in the 64-bit computer) register.

I'm guessing this is what automatically happens "behind the scenes" when programming in C, meaning the C compiler "knows" to use the `eax` register for functions returned values.

But what happens in C++, when the returned value is a big object that doesn't fit into the 32-bit `eax` or 64-bit `rax` register? Obviously you can't pass this using the stack, so how does the compiler handle a return-by-value operation of a big object?

Never mind a big object, how does the C compiler handle a return-by-value of a big structure?

Does it save it in a temporary memory space and returns its address as a return value? If so, it has to predict how many calls are to be done to the function during runtime, and sometimes it is impossible, isn't it?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366121/c-return-value-via-stack-register-question

Comment: `But what happens in C++?:` Are there any dedicated C compilers any more?

Comment: *"the convention regarding the caller-callee protocol states [...]"* Well, for one particular platform it does--and it is a very commonly deployed platform---but that is very much platform dependent. On other machines the registers may (i.e. often do) have different names and other stacks may use the same registers differently.

Comment: @40two [tcc](http://bellard.org/tcc/).

Comment: @dmckee I bet you use tcc on a regular basis :)

Comment: @40two Doesn't everyone?

Comment: @40two, I use a C dedicated compiler (gcc) on linux ubuntu.

Comment: @so.very.tired hmm... GCC is dedicated C compiler?

Comment: I think so... When I tried to compile a C++ code with it, it wouldn't let me, and I had to install g++

Comment: Not all processors have an `eax` register nor `rax`.

Comment: The thing about gcc is that it is both "GNU compiler collection" and "GNU c compiler". Which is to say that gcc (the compiler) is a subset of gcc (the overarching compilation complex).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Obviously you can't pass this using the stack...

Actually, the theory is that whenever a function is called and its stack frame is accommodated, it also makes room for the return object. It is then up to the calling function to ensure that that return value is copied somewhere within its own stack frame so that it can hold on to it.

This directly corresponds to how it works in C and C++. You have a `return ...;` statement, which copies some value into the return object. The return object is a temporary object, so the calling code has to store it somewhere, with something like `int value = foo();`.

However, it is pretty much never necessary to even bother with reserving space for the return value. Instead, the calling function makes room for it and the called function places the return value directly there. That's exactly what [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) is and what copy elision represents.

Comment: So when we say, "The compiler saves a temporary copy..." it actually saves it on the predesignated memory at the caller's stack frame?

Comment: @so.very.tired Yes, provided it is performing RVO (which any compiler in last however many years will do). That object is not temporary though, the temporary object is entirely removed. It's just storing the value directly in the object that the calling function is going to store the result in. So in the `int value = foo();` example, the `foo` function will store its result directly in `value`.

Comment: It must be noted that for RVO to work, you must not wrap the return value in std::move(), and also, there must be no implicit casts of the return value (returned object must match function signature).

Answer (score 15):

> Obviously you can't pass this using the stack

You can! The trick is to have the caller allocate the space on the stack, and let the function fill it in.

Essentially, the function returns the data in the caller's portion of the stack frame.

Answer (score 1):

You should imagine that the return value of a function goes onto the stack, like a local variable. And, like local variables, this can be optimized (and there are conventions depending on the architecture which dictate a well defined behavior) so that small return values go into registers instead of stack.